# Align two TextViews, one left the other right, on a ListView  without stretching the backgrounds

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, alignment, textview

So I've got two `TextViews` per row in a `ListView`. One should be left and the other right aligned. Both `TextViews` have a rounded rectangle as background which should just wrap the text inside. So I came up with this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble_purple"
        android:gravity="center" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/text_right"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble_blue"
        android:gravity="center" >
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

It looks good for long texts but not for shorter messages:

[image]

I also tried a LinearLayout like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble_blue"
        android:gravity="center" >
    </TextView>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble_purple"
        android:gravity="center">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This works for short messages but not for longer ones:

[image]

Is it somehow possible to measure the combined width of the `TextViews` and programmatically switch between these layouts, or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Try android:layout_weight="1" for both

Comment: How should the two `TextViews` stretch if the first one is small and the second one is big?

Comment: If the second `TextView` is larger but their combined width is smaller than the `ListView` it should look [like this](http://img109.imageshack.us/img109/760/linearlongright.png). Or, if their combined width is greater than the list width, [this](http://img195.imageshack.us/img195/1206/relativelongright.png) is the requested behaviour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does this work as you want?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:background="@drawable/bubble_blue"
    android:text="2"
    android:gravity="center" >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:background="@drawable/bubble_purple"
    android:text="9"
    android:gravity="center" >
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

By adding the layout_weight parameters and making them equal, you tell the layout engine to allocate any spare room equally between the two views.  If you wish the left block to be larger than the right, you can give it a larger weight.

**Edit:** Maybe this is better:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/text_left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#456"
        android:text="5 + 1"
        android:gravity="center" >
    </TextView> 

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=" = " >
</TextView>

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/text_right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:layout_weight="0.5">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#856"
            android:text="6"
            android:gravity="center" >
        </TextView>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: No, not exactly. Sure this works for long texts but for short texts this [stretches the backgrounds](http://img225.imageshack.us/img225/8269/linearstretchedbg.png). Ideally, the background should just wrap the text and there should be space between the bubbles for short messages, like in the second image above.

Comment: Nice! Wrapping them in `ViewGroups`, never thought of that. However, I got a "No resource identifier found" for `android:layoutDirection`. But switching the second inner `LinearLayout` to a `FrameLayout` and added a `android:layout_gravity="right"` did the trick. Thx!