# How to make a part of text in TextView bold?

Tags: android, textview

I have this TextViews:

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.carmodel)).setText("CarModel: " + getCarModel+"");
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.bikemodel)).setText("BikeModel: " + getBikeModel+"");
```

Is there a way to make bold just `CarModel:` and `BikeModel:`?

This is the XML file:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/carmodel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bikemodel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

So the `getCarModel` and `getBikeModel` will be italic and the `CarModel` and `BikeModel:` bold.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to make a specific text on TextView BOLD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371092/how-to-make-a-specific-text-on-textview-bold)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve what you want.

1) You can insert HTML inside your text view as explained by "Tanis" here "[How to display HTML in TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview)"

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.carmodel)).setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>CarModel: </h2>") + getCarModel+"");
```

2) You can create two text views like

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.carmodelBold)).setText("CarModel: ");    
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.carmodel)).setText(getCarModel);
```

and style the text view with ID "carmodelBold" as you want.

3) You can create a table

Comment: May be the second way will help me but how to put them on one row? Because if I make one textview for bold text and another for data they are on different lines?

Comment: I believe you are using lineraLayout with vertical orientation. You need to use linearLayout with horizontal orientation.

Comment: Just in case...You can nest layouts also. So if you cannot change the current layout, create a new layout inside it with desired orientation

Comment: Yes, I'm using LinearLayout and if I change it to `horizontal` everything is hided.. any example how to make it with nested layouts?

Comment: check these links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24931904/not-able-to-align-two-text-views-on-the-same-line-in-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927024/align-two-textviews-one-left-the-other-right-on-a-listview-without-stretching

Comment: But what if I have 9-10 textviews ... I must wrap every one in `LinearLayout`?

Comment: You must use the 3rd option. Wrap them in a table. That would be neater way to implement. You can google how to implement TableLayout in Android.

Comment: Ok, I will google it and try to make. Thank's for help so far